# Block access to project directory programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service running in Visual Studio. When running the service, the project's file structure shows up in the browser, and I have a directory containing some files for a user interface.

In my Web.config, I have an option (interfaceEnabled) for enabling/disabling the interface. When it is set to disabled, I would like to completely disable access to the directory containing the interface files, but I don't know how to do this.

I know that setting "hiddensegment" in Web.config can do this, but I need to do it programmatically based on the value of interfaceEnabled.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without coding the whole thing for you I would use

```
string setting = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Settingname"]
```

Then if Setting is true or what ever condition you like, Change the directory permissions using Directory.SetAccessControl

There are a few articles on changing folder permissions in C# I am unsure if this is a good idea to begin with as changing the perms for the folder while your app is running from it might cause issues or not work.